# How to store an IEnumerable and a string that describes it together

Tags: c#, wpf, string, ienumerable

The IEnumerable in question is a list of an object containing filenames and properties relating to those file names, and the string is a directory name, such as "C:\Test\Testing". My goal is to store these two pieces of data together so that they're 'linked', in a sense, which should make them easier to use together, as the IEnumerable will become the source for a DataGrid, and the string the text of a label stating the current directory.

How would I go about achieving this? I initially thought of a dictionary, but that doesn't seem to work here. I need to be able to grab the 'top-most' item, so to speak, whenever a button is pressed, and dictionaries are, I believe, unordered.

Comment: There is an OrderedDictionary class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A `SortedList` may do too.

Comment: @BenRobinson would that allow me to get the top-most element? Well, the element most recently put into it

Comment: You can retrieve any item you want by index e.g. `MyOrderedDictionary.Item[3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the accepted answer works, I would recommend creating a class for this, rather than using a `KeyValuePair`:

```
public class FilesInDirectory
{
    public string Directory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> FileNames { get; set; }
}
```

In OOP you should strive to avoid [primitive obsession](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/primitive-obsession). A `KeyValuePair` is a kind of primitive, as it doesn't convey any meaning and can't be extended.

- **Meaning**: When you're iterating over the list and dealing with `item.Key` and then iterating over `item.Value`, things will get confusing - far less so than `item.Directory` and `item.FileNames`
- **Extension**: You will want to define some methods that extract data from these items, or process them in some way - usually, these methods are better off on the data item itself. For example you might want to get a list of actual file objects. With a `KeyValuePair`, you will have to define that method on some other class, whereas it actually fits right at home on `FilesInDirectory.GetFiles()`

Comment: This sounds a lot better; switched accepted to this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about a `List<KeyValuePair<IEnumerable, string>>`?

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<IEnumerable, string>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<IEnumerable, string>(data, path));
```

If that sounds too awkward for you, feel free to use a custom class instead.

---

Feel free to use a `Queue<>`, `Stack<>` or anything else that fits your needs, `KeyValuePair` can be used with any collection type.